# Vulkan, DRI, X11, and KMS: how do they relate?

Tags: linux, x11, drivers, gpu, vulkan

I think I have a decent understanding of the chain of software that gets graphics code from a program to your hardware, but I would like someone to correct me on any mistakes.

When I write a program (in C, let's say) that uses Vulkan to render and present a 3D scene, I have to link to `libvulkan`. `libvulkan` actually just dispatches my commands to the Vulkan library for my platform. This library makes calls into `libdrm` which talks to the kernel driver using the `/dev/dri/renderX` interface. This driver then interacts with my hardware.

To recap:

```
program -> libvulkan -> libvulkan_platform -> libdrm -> /dev/dri/renderX -> kernel drm driver -> hardware
```

Is this correct?

In addition, once the GPU has rendered my frames, they need to be presented on the screen. This is done by sending them to the platform's window library (X11, wayland, etc) using the Vulkan window system integration (WSI) layer. However, when I write programs in Vulkan, I also use `glfw`. where does it come in? The window server then has to display the composited frames on the display, also using libdrm. it interacts with the kernel KMS driver through the `/dev/dri/cardX` interface, which then interacts with the hardware.

To recap:

```
program -> libvulkan (wsi) -> glfw??? -> libX11, libwayland-client -> X server (Xorg) + modesetting_drv, Wayland compositor -> libdrm -> /dev/dri/cardX -> platform KMS driver -> hardware
```

Is this correct?